# Too many years options to be built

Tags: forms, date, ruby-on-rails-3.2

After upgrading from Rails 3.0x to 3.2.11 I got the following error:

```
There're too many years options to be built. Are you sure you haven't mistyped something? You can provide the :max_years_allowed parameter
```

Code:

```
<%= f.date_select :to,
    :start_year => Time.now.year - 80,
    :discard_day => true,
    :include_blank => true %>
```

I've also tried to include a :max_years_allowed parameter without success, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the rails docs the `select_year` method in `date_select` sets `max_years_allowed` to 1000 if the option isn't passed in. It then looks to see if the absolute value of the ending year minus the starting year is greater than the `max_years_allowed` option. Have you opened up the rails console and checked that `Time.now.year - 80` isn't giving a year more than 1000 years ago? I know it sounds crazy, but it's about the only reason I could see you getting that error.

Here's [the link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateTimeSelector/select_year).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try like this, it works.

```
<%= f.date_select :to,
    :start_year => 80.years.ago.year,
    :discard_day => true,
    :include_blank => true %>
```